# Saving python datetime value to a mySQL timestamp with timezone field

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am baffled.

I assign to a Django model field as follows:

```
listing.modify_date =  datetime.now()
```

where the field is defined as:

```
listing_modify_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Printing out the assigned value...

```
print("modify_date=" + str(listing.modify_date))
```

I get:

```
modify_date=2020-12-18 21:35:09.178392
```

But the mySQL table is not updated.

However:

1. non-"timestamp with timezone" fields in the row are updated;
2. The following query in pgAdmin updates modify_date:

   update public.listings_listing
   set listing_modify_date = '2020-12-01 15:00:01'

I have run out of things to try. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> But the mySQL table is not updated.

The name of the field is `listing_modify_date` so:

```
listing.listing_modify_date = datetime.now() 
listing.save()
```

but as you found out yourself, using `datetime.now()` is *not* a good idea, because it does not cotain any timezone information. Django has defined a more advanced function for this: [**`timezone.now()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

listing.listing_modify_date = now()
listing.save()
```

Furthermore you do not need to specify the `modify_date`: you can work with [**`auto_now=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now):

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    # …
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This will update the field each time you update that object (and save it to the database). It will also mark the field as non-editable, so it will not, by default, appear in `ModelForm`s you make with this model.

Comment: Gulp! You are right. My excuse is that I was just too close to the code to catch something so elemental. Thanks also for the elaboration. All helpful.